# Merge edit and create post methods into 1 in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a edit and create post method in my controller and apart from calling a different method in my service are identical. I'm just wondering if there is a way of merging these methods into 1.  Can I check the route in an if statement?

```
  [Route("Project/{projectnumber}/Structures/{structureid}/Carbon/Create")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CarbonViewModel carbonViewModel){
            Carbon Carbon = _Mapper.Map<CarbonViewModel, Carbon>(carbonViewModel);

            if (!_CarbonService.InsertCarbon(Carbon)) {
                return View(carbonViewModel);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { 
                projectNumber = carbonViewModel.ProjectNumber, 
                structureId = carbonViewModel.StructureId 
            });
        }

[Route("Project/{projectnumber}/Structures/{structureid}/Carbon/Edit")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(CarbonViewModel carbonViewModel){
        Carbon Carbon = _Mapper.Map<CarbonViewModel, Carbon>(carbonViewModel);

        if (!_CarbonService.UpdateCarbon(Carbon)) {
            return View(carbonViewModel);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {
            projectNumber = carbonViewModel.ProjectNumber,
            structureId = carbonViewModel.StructureId
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can have just one method and specify the action and controller names in the form tag. Assuming your model has a ID property, then you can check if your creating or editing based on the value of the ID (e.g. `if (carbonViewModel.ID.HasValue) { // update } else { insert }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Carbon.ID.HasValue)
{
   //you code for update
}
else
{
   //your code for add
}
```